# Android correct layout not visible

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gridview

I am looking to implement a layout similar to the Windows 8 metro UI with 2 small square shaped grid items on top of a larger rectangle shaped one. I am using the following code for this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#eeeeee" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#eeeeee" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:columnWidth="170dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
            android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:src="@drawable/aloha2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

However, I am only able to view the first 2 grid items but not the image view below it like this.

[image]

Why is the rectangular image view not being displayed here ?
What mistake am I making?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need all these layouts... just a GridLayout and 3 children. Tutorial: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_the_Android_GridLayout_in_XML_Layout_Resources

Comment: android:layout_height="fill_parent" in RelativeLayout might be the cause.

Comment: @DerGolem but won't using a gridlayout give me 3 square shaped images?I am looking for 2 squares on top of one rectangle.

Comment: mention the android:layout_height="wrap_content" in RelativeLayout it's working

Comment: **NO**, because, **like in HTML**, you can use `layout_columnSpan="2"` for the lower ImageView

Answer (score 2):

please try with below code In your code you had take the RelativeLayout and give the fill_parent height property to it which was useless
if you want to take the RelativeLayout you have to assign the below property to your bottom RelativeLaytout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#eeeeee" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:columnWidth="170dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
            android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:src="@drawable/aloha2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove the Relative layout..it may be hide your imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Your RelativeLayout is filling parent. try to make it in wrap content like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#eeeeee" 
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#eeeeee" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:columnWidth="170dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:src="@drawable/aloha2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp" />
```

Comment: Yes I can see the imageview now. But it still doesn't stretch the entire width of the screen as I would like and is a square centered in the middle. Why so ?

Comment: Use `android weight`. ,in your ImageView layout:
    `android:layout_weight="1"`

Thanks to that, the image view will cover 100% of the free space below it.